# 2 GET to same resource in Python Flask Restful

Tags: flask-restful

I want to have these 2 routes in my api
GET /students/ID  (Fetching all student personal details, by student ID)
GET /students/ID/grades  (Fetch all grades of specific student, by student ID)

Grades are related to student specific student.

What is the best way to implement this scenario?
I must have 2 Resources? One for student and one for grades?
Seems to me like a recipe for a long long code, or this is the right way?

Thanks Alon

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must have two `Resource` instances.

Each will implement its own `get` method and bind to Api with its own URL path via `api.add_resource(ResourceClass, '/url/here')`.